# margin-left is not working in asp.net label

Tags: asp.net

Please find my code below.

```
<div style="position:relative">
    <asp:Label ID="lbl_details" runat="server" style="margin-top:50px;display:inline-block" Text="Details"
               Width="150px"></asp:Label>

    <textarea id="txtarea_details" runat="server" cssclass="textbox" maxlength="150" columns="30" rows="5"
              style="border:1px solid #CCC; margin-top:0px; margin-left:0px; width:191px; white-space:pre-wrap"></textarea>
    <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server"
               Text="&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Remarks"
               Width="345px"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_remarks" runat="server" style="margin-top:0px;" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>

</div>
```

Comment: Try: margin-left:-30px; (minus)

Comment: What is your question???

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div style="position:relative">
    <div style="width:30%;float:left,text-allign:right,padding:50px,0px,0px,15px">
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_details" runat="server" Text="Details" ></asp:Label>
    </div>

       <div style="width:70%;float:left,text-allign:left,padding:50px,0px,0px,15px">
        <textarea id="txtarea_details" runat="server" cssclass="textbox" maxlength="150" columns="30" rows="5"
                  style="border:1px solid #CCC; margin-top:0px; margin-left:0px; width:191px; white-space:pre-wrap"></textarea>
<div style="width:30%;float:left,text-allign:right,padding:50px,0px,0px,15px">
      <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server"Text="Remarks"
                   Width="345px"></asp:Label>
</div>
<div style="width:70%;float:left,text-allign:right,padding:50px,0px,0px,15px">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_remarks" runat="server" style="margin-top:0px;" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </div>
```